# Boot Error 1962 - Lenovo 93p tiny

Tags: uefi, openmediavault

Hope this is the right place to post this regarding Debian/Unbuntu simularities.
I've installed OPM via a USB key onto another USB key which I'm now booting from. However, each time I turn the machine on from cold (not a reboot) I get the following error:
Error 1962: No operating system found. Boot sequence will automatically repeat.
If I CtrlAltDel 3 times at this screen, it will eventually boot into Grub and I can run OMV.

I can't work out why this is happening and it doesn't simply boot into grub first time? From searching I'm aware that this seems like an issue with Lenovo boards/bios. However because I'm a total newbie at linux I'm having difficulty finding out if there's an actual fix? People are mentioning possible partition issues, mounting them differently, UEFI? My background is windows based so I don't know how I'd go about acting on those subjects within Debian?

My bios startup settings are that I've removed all other devices from it except the USB which is holding the OS (USB HDD 1) and the USB Key setting itself. I've CSM enabled, Boot Mode set to 'Auto' and Boot Priority set to 'UEFI First'.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how to solve this problem? One from a beginners perspective? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) You'll see that support is provided for only currently supported versions of Ubuntu and its official flavors, namely, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Kylin, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Studio and Xubuntu. Your question seems to be about Debian and so may be welcome at our related site: [unix.se].

Comment: This might not be the right place for this question. The message you're getting is from either BIOS or Grub and happens **before** you get into your Debian/Ubuntu system. I would try to ask this question on Grub or Dell/Lenovo message boards.

Comment: [SOLVED] Error 1962: No operating system found. Lenovo K430  only boot Ubuntu, rename files
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243715  Are you sure you want the old BIOS boot mode, not newer UEFI boot mode? CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off.